# What should I do during triaging if a question is already edited?

Tags: discussion, review, triage

I have just earned my privilege to review questions and help with triaging, so I started pitching in today.  I came across a question which in my opinion needed editing but was already edited.  Should I:

1. Looks OK - ignores the fact that I feel the quality of the question could have been improved.
2. Requires Editing - potentially duplicating work and if a second editor looks at it and concurs with the first editor then this is meaningless.
3. Unsalvageable - Kind of an irrelevant option, but I can see a scenario where I feel the question is unsalvageable, but was already edited by someone who didn't.
4. Skip - This - I assume - just throws it back on the heap for another triager to deal with who will likely have the same questions I did.

If this has been asked and answered already, I could use a link cause I couldn't really find anything with the search terms I used.

Comment: If it's OK by the time you see it, "Looks OK" is what you should choose - it doesn't matter how it  looked like in the past.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree, I was really trying to see what others thought if it doesn't look ok by the time I see it.  I don't have a link to the question anymore, and didn't actually triage it, so I can't point you to it, but the question had some awkward language and was missing a tag so I felt it could have been edited even further.

Comment: I'm confused, should I have asked this over at SO?  This has nothing to do with programming...  Or what should I have said to make it fit into Meta?  I think this is a legitimate question, how/where should I have asked it?

Comment: Triage currently exists only on SO so some people think all questions about it belongs to MSO. I am not one of them, voting to reopen.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks, I didn't realize every site also had an associated meta site.  This does make sense now, although, if it's going to be rolled out to all sites eventually, then I can see its value being here rather than being re-asked in hundreds of metas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether the post has been edited is irrelevant.  If the post looks okay now, mark it as okay.  If the post needs editing in its current state, indicate that it needs editing.  If the post is unsalvageable, flag it as appropriate.

Comment: I see your point, but then aren't we really just duplicating work?  I mean the post has been edited already, isn't the person editing the post, in effect also pre-emptively "triaging" it?

Comment: @akousmata If the post needs additional work after already being edited then no, it's not duplicating anything.  Making additional edits to fix additional problems isn't duplicating any work..  The fact that one person has edited a post once doesn't mean that the post is magically perfect and no longer has any problems, or that the editor is somehow obligated to make additional edits to fix every other problem that remains.

Comment: Fair enough, this is more or less how I felt about it, but I just wanted to get other people's take on it.